# ng-click HTML code works fine but same code in an angularjs function.ng-click does not working

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-click

### HTML

```
<div id="rightpane">
  <div id="rightpanecontent" >  
     <div id ="Addbtn" style="text-align: right;"> 
     <button type="btnAdd" class="btnAddText" ng-click="addText()" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:166px; color: white;background-color:#673ab7;">Add Text</button>
   </div>
  <div class="si-note-separator" ></div> 
 <div id="myDIV" style="display: none;">     
 <textarea ng-model="imagecomment" name="taname" id="taid" wrap="soft" ></textarea>
  <button type="button" 
ng-click="addCommentToImage()" >Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

`Controller.js` file.(need to make `html` code dynamic,so put it in `controller.js` `file.ng-click` does not work)

```
function load() {
    var text = '';
     text = text + '<div id ="Addbtn" style="text- 
      align:right;">' + '<button type="btnAdd" class="btnAdd" click="Add()" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:166px; color: white;background-color:#673ab7;">Add</button>'+
    '</div>' +
  '<div class="si-note-separator" ></div>'+ '<div id="myDIV">'+     
  '<textarea ng-model="comment" name="taname" id="taid" wrap="soft" ></textarea>'+
 '<button type="button" ng-click="addComment()" >Save</button>'+
      '</div>';
 }
```

Comment: you need to not just render it, but compile it as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any dynamic thing your load function template, I'd recommend you to keep this html inside `html` file and load the same using `ng-include` directive

**template.html**

```
<div>
    <div id ="Addbtn" style="text- 
          align:right;">
        <button type="btnAdd" class="btnAdd" click="Add()" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:166px; color: white;background-color:#673ab7;">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="si-note-separator" ></div>
    <div id="myDIV">
      <textarea ng-model="comment" name="taname" id="taid" wrap="soft" ></textarea
      <button type="button" ng-click="addComment()" >Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Usage

```
<div ng-include="clicked ? '': 'template.html'"></div>
```

Just on click of button toggle `clicked` flag.

---

The other way would be adding the html content inside DOM and compile it using `$compile` service, which helps angular relative code and triggers the respective `directive`/`component` for the same.

```
element.append($compile(text)($scope));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your html dynamic then you'll have to compile it using `$compile` service, so that it can be attached to the `scope` object. Then only `ng-click` will work.